# Comma needed before a sentence-ending "then"?

Tags: punctuation

Do I use a comma before "then" in this example?

> Joe said, "If she plans on going, I won't be there, then."

Comment: Both alternatives are fine. But they have different meanings.

Comment: That is what I am unsure of. What's the difference with and without the comma?

Comment: Joe said, "If she plans on going, I won't be there then." = Joe said, "If she plans on going, I won't be there when she is." (temporal adverb) // Joe said, "If she plans on going, I won't be there, then." =  Joe said, "In that case, if she plans on going, I won't be there." (pragmatic marker (giving reason: what Joe has just learnt))

Answer (score 2):

> She is going to that party? I won't be there, then.

This means I will not be at the party, *because* she's going (and I have no wish to meet her).
This *then* is part of an *if, then* construction, where the *if* is suppressed: *if she's going, then I am not going*.

> She is going to the party? I won't be there then.

This means that I will not be present *at that time*.

This *then* is simply temporal, and the sentence is similar to *I won't be there tonight*.

Answer (score 1):

By adding a comma, the "then" relates to the condition in the first part of the sentence.

On the other hand - if there's no comma, then this whole sentence doesn't make much sense because the "then" would relate to an exact point in time when Joe would not be there.

The comma version suits better.